# CSS Descendant Selectors: Some Work While Some Do Not

Tags: html, css

I am trying to style a nav link to be a certain color when I am on that page.

HTML:

```
 <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html" class="selected">Portfolio</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

CSS:

```
nav a.selected {
  color: #000;
}
```

The above code works. But if I removed the nav selector and just used

```
a.selected {
  color: #000;
}
```

then the code doesn't work.

**What if I wanted anywhere that I have an anchor element with a class "selected" to have #000?**

Comment: There is absolutely no reason why `a.selected` will not work unless you have a higher specificity selector overriding it. Can't comment without a demo or your full code.

Comment: This works for me with just the code you have shown. I think @Harry is on the right track.

Comment: your code is working:
https://jsfiddle.net/024c9et7/

Comment: You guys are right, it's a rookie mistake as I'm learning CSS. I have the below code right above it:

    `a {
      color: #6ab47b;
    }`

Comment: I'm 99% certain that rule wouldn't override the rule immediately below.

Comment: I'm with @Rounin. Except I'm 100% sure. Check https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity. Type selectors are less specific then Class selectors. In the element inspector in your browsers you should be able to analyse which styles are overwriting yours.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here seems to be the ***specificity*** of your selector.

Meaning:

```
nav a.selected {
  color: #000;
}
```

Is not as exact as:

```
nav ul li a.selected {
  color: #000;
}
```

Which holds more significance than the above.

So in order for your `a.selected` to work, You need to remove the `nav` before it, making it a ***global*** modulator just as the color you applied to your global anchor modulator, or apply the more specific selector from above (the second block):

```
a {
  color: #6ab47b;
}
a.selected {
  color: #000;
}
```

As a learner, I suggest You try and stick to the **[Mozilla Developer Network (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)** Almanac.